# MCIERR_DEVICE_OPEN error with mciSendString() c++

Tags: c++, audio, mci, mcisendstring

I'm trying to make a simple audio player class for C++. I've been using `mciSendString()` to actually play the audio.

The class constructor passes in a string for the file location (`File`), and then it checks to see if it can actually open the file. The way I have that going is that it tries to get the length of the audio file, and when it can't get anything then it prints the MCI error.

```cpp
// return false if file cannot be opened
void openFile(const std::string& file) {
    bool opened = true;

    // check if file is empty
    std::string S2 = "status " + file + " length";
    char buffer[128];

    std::string err = mciErrorLookup( // mciErrorLookup is a function that i made that returns the mci error as a string
        mciSendString(TEXT(S2.c_str()), buffer, 128, NULL)
    );

    try {
        // tries to convert the buffer, which should hold the length of the audio, to string
        auto _ = std::stoi(buffer);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        opened = false;
    }

    if (!opened)
        // if opened is false, then "err" must be something
        // [if mciSendString does not return an error then "err" will equal "unknown error"]
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open audio file \"" + file + "\"\n" + err);
    }
```

The audio class works fine on a few of my audio files, shorter mp3s (~7Kb and ~30Kb). But when I try to play a song (larger file, 4.96Mb), `openFile()` throws `MCIERR_DEVICE_OPEN`.

Microsoft docs say "The device name is already used as an alias by this application. Use a unique alias." for `MCIERR_DEVICE_OPEN`. What I don't understand is why this is working fine for smaller files but then not working for larger files.

I've looked all over but can't find anything about `mciSendString()` limitations for audio file sizes. I did see something about it not working if the directory name was too large, but even when I shortened the directory for the large audio file the error persisted. I'm not sure what I should do as I'm not even 100% sure what is happening. Any help would be appreciated.